# Why did a simple || work like an if sequence?

Tags: php, if-statement

In my last project I had to specify a value, normally I use the following statement:

```
<?php 
  $true = 1;
  $false = 0;
  $hasAccess = $true ? 1 : 0;
  print $hasAccess;
?>
```

but this works to:

```
<?php 
  $true = 1;
  $false = 0;
  $hasAccess = $true || $false;
  print $hasAccess;
?>
```

Why?

***Update:*** I know what a OR / || is and what I have to expect from it. But I haven't seen this possibility any time before.

Comment: And why didn't you just write $hasAccess = 1?

Comment: Seeing a variable called `$true` that's not boolean makes me feel uneasy...

Comment: Is the PHP manual that useless?

Comment: I had asked, because I didn't found an answer (in my books, manuals ,www or Google) Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: And a big thank you to all the other guys, which take their time, to give me an answer :D Now I understand it. Sometimes I can't see the wood for the trees ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 0 is automaticly casted to (bool)false, and anything else (bool)true.
So what you are basicly saying is:

`$hasaccess = true OR false;`

See also:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
$true ? 1 : 0;
```

evaluates to `1`, since `$true` is true, and

```
$true || $false;
```

also evaluates to `1`, for the same reason.

Comment: Doesn't the last one evaluate to `true`?

Answer (score 0):

The OR will return true if either side of the expression true.

Since $true = 1 then the expression as a whole is true.

Basically you're saying "if $true is true, or $false is true then then $hasAccess is true"

Answer (score 0):

An || which is an OR statement returns weather one of the statements evaluates to true.
Examples:

```
$bool = true || false;
// $bool = true

$bool = false || true;
// $bool = true

$bool = false || false;
// $bool = false

$bool = false || true || false;
// $bool = true

$bool = false || 1;
// $bool = true

$bool = false || 'test';
// $bool = true
```